# Documentation for forceCommunity:search Interface

Tags: lightning-aura-components, documentation

Does anyone know where Salesforce has documentation for the `forceCommunity:searchInterface` interface? They have a really quick example on the developer page but do not detail how to actually fire or handle a search event.

Comment: which developer page is it referred ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_components.htm mentions it, but I can't seem to find docs either.

Comment: @DS which example are you referring to ?At sfdcfox there is more documentation than that but want to make sure DS has looked into it and i am not pasting same docs he is looking at :D

Comment: @MohithShrivastava The only doc I could find is https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm?search_text=forcecommunity and the release note sfdcfox listed above.

Comment: Just expanded the answer to be more precise .Let me know if you need further info .I can write thesis on this subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forceCommunity:searchInterface` does not handle events .You basically replace the standard search with the new interface in your community settings .

The developer [guide has an example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm?search_text=forcecommunity)

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface" access="global">
<div class="search">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <form class="search-form">
            <div class="search-input-wrapper">
                <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="My Search"/>
            </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
        </form>
    </div>
   </div>
 </aura:component>
```

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Lets say you want to configure which objects then you will need to configure that in the community builder

[image]

As you can see there are global search results and search results components .Depending on what you need you drop them on search layout

[image]

Global search results allows you to add the objects you want to search against .

If you further wish to write your own component and show results for not suported objects then you can do so using the standard design variables found in builder.Here is a github link where i was able to pull external data into the builder

https://github.com/CodeScience/MidwestDreamin/tree/master/metadata/aura/youtubeSearch

[image]

Comment: Right, this is the example they provide. What happens when that search is submitted? How would you display results? What objects are you searching on?

Comment: Enhanced the answer .Let me know if you need more info here

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will run through this as soon as I can.

Comment: Quick question, in your youtube code sample how is the `{!searchString}` value  passed to your results component? Is this some sort of pseudo-global value provider that gets set when a value gets entered into the top search bar? Our use case for search is similar to your example where we would like to pass the search entered by the user in the top area to a custom controller we have to return non-SObject results so thanks for providing that very valuable example.

Comment: @DS Thats correct .Thats a pseudo global variable .You will need a design file for that and configure that in your builder .I had blogged about same as well here http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2016/01/customizing-napili-template-of-sfdc-for.html

Comment: Thanks for that link to your blog, it makes sense now that these attributes are really application attributes of the community app that our components can access since they are children of that application. It would be great if Salesforce documented this, but that is just wishful thinking. I'll take this info and try to spin up a custom component to consume that search string.

Comment: What to do when you just want to change how the search bar look and keep using Global Search? I have replaced the default search with a custom component but nothing happen.

Comment: You will need to overwrite the CSS for that using custom themeing .